# register a font with Raphael using CSS3 @font-face

Tags: jquery, css, svg, raphael

In my pages I often use custom fonts with the Raphaël .print with
the .getFont. for SVG text, and the CSS3 @font-face (with Font
Squirrel kits) for normal text.
Is maybe possible to automatically register a font from the @font-face
property, without create a JSON with Cufon?

I saw that in Font Squirrel kit there's the format('svg') used for old
iPhone/iPad ("This is an XML format required by iOS devices before
version 4.2.") maybe it could be useful also for desktop...

Thank you

Comment: You should just be able to set the font in SVG with CSS, the same as with HTML.  There's no need to use actual SVG fonts unless you want to manipulate the outlines or something.  What code do you have at the moment?

Answer (score 2):

If you define a font using @font-face in your css, you can then apply it to a Raphaël paper.text object in this way :

```
var someText = paper.text(0, 0, 'this is some text');           
someText.attr({'font-family':'myCustomFont'});
```

Comment: Does not work for me in IE8... Is there a way to declare src (in @font-face) in the css file for that to work? Is it working with google fonts ?

Comment: Yes it works with google fonts. I have to admit, I only used this on SVG compatible browsers (including IE9), whereas IE8 is not SVG compatible.